# file/page not found when uploaded online

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, filenotfoundexception

I am working on a new module of existing live project. It is a website developed in PHP Zend Framework. New module is on admin side. It runs properly on my localhost/virtualhost.
When I uploaded it online with correct directory path it is found that one file is not found.
It is called like

> www.example.com/admin/controllerName/***actionName***

All the actions works except one action that doesn't display anything and returns exception error mentioning that page or file not found.
What could be the issue? I have checked folders. If one action for the same controller works than why doesn't other. Both have their .phtml files in View section.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Also, you should go over some of your previous questions and accept some answers - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Phil : No, it's not generating stack trace and nor it is error. Just displaying the defined error "the requested page was not found" in main body area. While the display layout is loaded with header, footer, menu.. etc.

Comment: Have you enabled logging? If not, you could enable error reporting to quickly test it in the `application.ini` file on-line, eg `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would I be right if I guessed your local development environment was Windows?

It's probably a filename case sensitivity issue.

Assuming your request looks like

```
www.example.com/admin/fusionmaps/newpage
```

I'm not sure how you've setup your modules but if it's reasonably standard, you should have something like this (note the upper and lowercase characters)

```
application/modules/admin/controllers/FusionmapsController.php
```

The controller classname should be `Admin_FusionmapsController` with action `public function newpageAction()`

The view script should be at

```
application/modules/admin/views/scripts/fusionmaps/newpage.phtml
```

Comment: Yes it is WAMP environment. ControllerName and actionNames are followed like that using standard conventions. If is not like that anyways does it make difference when running on wamp than online? The existing website is running since two years.

Comment: @maniclorn Windows filesystems are case-insensitive whereas Unix / Linux ones are the opposite. What OS is your production site running? What are the actual file names and paths?

Comment: @ Phil: **www.example.com/admin/fusionmaps/viewpage**  one another action in masterpage www.example.com/admin/fusionmaps/mapsmaster having included search form and using **search** action works fine. But, other running modules have the same naming conventions and I followed the same style.

Comment: @maniclorn and what are the controller filename, classname and action method name? It should be `FusionmapsController.php`, `Admin_FusionmapsController` and `viewpageAction()`

Comment: FusionmapsController.php ; class Admin_FusionmapsController ; public function newpageAction() ;

Comment: sorry, I wrote viewpage in previous comment by mistske. It is newpage.

Comment: @maniclorn If you have it exactly as in my edited answer, it should be working. If not, you'll just need to collect some error information. See my comment on your question

Comment: Thanks. Hoping the comment would be useful. But, I have no rights of FTP and project upload. It is controlled by my project manager.